# Android crash on CompletationHintView

Tags: android

I have a problem with android:completionHintView in a AutoCompleteTextView.

I have in my layout this AutoCompleteTextView:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/customer_autocomplete"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:completionHintView="@layout/customer_autocomplet_hint"
            android:completionHint="@string/customer_label"
            android:popupBackground="#F00"
            android:dropDownHeight="wrap_content"
            android:dropDownVerticalOffset="0dp"
            android:dropDownAnchor="@+id/dropdownDivider"
            android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/robotomedium"/>
```

The interesting part is:

**android:completionHintView="@layout/customer_autocomplete_hint"
android:completionHint="@string/customer_label"**

Because then I have a layout named customer_autocomplete_hint:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/customer_label"
    android:textColor="#FFF" android:textSize="16sp" />
```

And it Work, but my question is:
Why **If I put anything id instead of**

```
android:id="@android:id/text1"
```

the app crash with following error?

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #147: Binary XML
>   file line #15: Error inflating class AutoCompleteTextView
>           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class AutoCompleteTextView
>           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference

**NOTE**

I haven't any references in my code that make a setText on resource with **@+id/text1** or others or **android:id="@id/text1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `AutoCompleteTextView` looks for `TextView` with ID `R.id.text1` when setting completion hint as specified in `android:completionHint` in your XML layout. You can see it in `AutoCompleteTextView` [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-r6-release/core/java/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java#332).

```
public void setCompletionHint(CharSequence hint) {
    mHintText = hint;
    if (hint != null) {
        if (mHintView == null) {
            final TextView hintView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mPopupContext).inflate(
                    mHintResource, null).findViewById(R.id.text1);  // Here it looks for text1 ID
            hintView.setText(mHintText);
            mHintView = hintView;
            mPopup.setPromptView(hintView);
        } else {
            mHintView.setText(hint);
        }
    } else {
        mPopup.setPromptView(null);
        mHintView = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, yes ok, But It crash even if I put:
android:id="@+id/text1".
I expected that this way it won't crash.

Comment: `android:id="@+id/text1"` means that you are creating (because of +, the syntax is `@[+][package:]id/resource_name`) new ID text1 in your package. Android looks for `R.id.text1`, which means you have specify ID which was declared in Android, therefore using `@android:id/text1`